# Can someone explain why this doeasn't work? The default constructor of "B" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, default-constructor

I'm currently making c++ project but this error is bothering me for long time and i cannot figure out why this doesn't work.
I was searching about this error but still i don't understand it.

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class A
{
public:
    int a = 0;
    A(int _a) : a(a) {}
};

class B
{
public:
    A a;
    void test()
    {
        A a1(6);
        a = a1;
    }
};
    
int main()
{
    B b1;
    b1.test();

    
    return 0;

}
```

I tried to initialized value in constructor in class and this worked but what if i don't want to do this?

Comment: class `A` has no default constructor; so `B::a` can't be default constructed.  This causes deletion the generation of the default constructor for `B`.  Read the details of the error messages - live - https://godbolt.org/z/YTedeK1sG

Comment: To close voters: the beginner-level mistake is not a typo, and this shouldn't be closed as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your member initialization list in `A`'s converting constructor is wrong. `a(a)` should be `a(_a)` instead.

Second, `A` has a user-defined constructor, so its compiler-generated default constructor is implicitly `delete`'d.

Thus, `B::a` can't be default-constructed, so `B`'s compiler-generated default constructor is also implicitly `delete`'d.

Thus, `b1` in `main()` can't be default-constructed, either.

If you want `A` to be default-constructible, you need to either:

- add a default constructor explicitly:

```
class A
{
public:
    int a = 0;
    A() {}; // or: A() = default; // <-- HERE
    A(int _a) : a(_a) {}
};
```

- Change your converting constructor so it can also act as a default constructor:

```
class A
{
public:
    int a = 0;
    A(int _a = 0) : a(_a) {} // <-- HERE
};
```

Otherwise, you will have to add a default constructor to `B` to construct `B::a` with a value:

```
class B
{
public:
    A a;
    B() : a(0) {} // <-- HERE
    void test()
    {
        A a1(6);
        a = a1;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`A` doesn't have a default constructor so it cannot be default constructed.

A class object must be fully initialized before entering the body of the constructor which means that in `B` you need to initialize `a` (either with data member init or with constructor list initialization).

If for whatever reason you want to delay the initialization of `a` you have a few options. Depending on the semantics of it you could make it `std::optional<A> a` or `std::unique_ptr<A>`.